# iPhone 4 iOS 7 Songs Not Staying on Phone Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: rhythmbox, music, iphone

I have an iPhone 4 running iOS 7 (I will be switching away from Apple at next upgrade).  I can connect to computer, without any "Trust this computer" loops like many people, because I installed the newest `libimobiledevice`.  I am now trying to sync my music using Rhythmbox.

Rhythm will let me drag/drop music onto the iPhone, and even says that the music I've added is on the phone.  But when I eject the iPhone the music I thought I added isn't there.  If I leave the phone connected to my computer but close and reopen Rhythmbox, it shows that the music I hoped to sync is not present.

I installed Rhythmbox 3.0.1 according to [these](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-rhythmbox-30-in-ubuntu-1310-or.html) instructions, but the issue did not go away.

Has anyone had success with this issue, or an Idean about where I should be looking for  guidance (i.e. where the Rhythmbox logs might be, to see if there is some silent error)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the libimobiledevice website Music Synchronization does not work with *DBVersion > 4*. This is the case for iPhone 4 and newer:

> The iPhone 4/4S, iPod Touch 4, iPad 1/2/3rd Gen and Apple TV do NOT work.
>   Any device with DBVersion > 4 does NOT work. To check your DBVersion run "ideviceinfo -q com.apple.mobile.iTunes -k DBVersion". WIP.

---

In order to get your music on your iPhone, you can either try to run iTunes with wine or you use a third-party player on your iPhone.

Seeing the state of the [wine compatiblility page for iTunes](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347) you may need some luck.

When I was confronted with the same problem I went with the alternate player option. (I'm using [AcePlayer](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/aceplayer-leistungsstarken/id463242636?mt=8), which even plays ogg-vorbis, although playlist handling could be better). Use `ideviceinstaller -l` to find the APPID of the player. Then just mount it with `ifuse /mount/point --appid APPID` and copy the files you want. Unmount with `fusermount -u /mount/point`.

Comment: That sucks about libmobiledevice - I was hoping I was just kind of dumb.  I'll look into AcePlayer (or a new phone :P )